# Freeze frame video editor

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-editor

I am looking for a video editor to create freeze frames and create text on top of the frozen frame than export it as a new video. An example of what I am trying to achieve can be seen in this Youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sOqNMqqKOw

But he uses [VSDC Video Editor](http://www.videosoftdev.com/video-editor-doc/system-requirements) in that video which is Windows based only.

Do we have an Ubuntu alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Openshot](http://www.openshot.org/features/) video editor on standard Ubuntu. If you use KDE, the best option would be [KDEnlive](https://kdenlive.org/).

The technique is to stop the video, make a still of the last frame and use this for the text with the title generator. Afterwards, you splice this into your clip with the desired length. This can be done in all but the simplest video editors.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5ZouktdUrw) is a YouTube tutorial video which shows how to do the freeze frame with KDEnlive.

Answer (score 0):

Actually most of the Video Editing Software can do this.
Could you choose one of the Video Editing Software from [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894185/movie-splitter-or-movie-maker/894224#894224), and continue with your self learning, Go Through Video Course.

I suggest two link for Learning this effect (2nd link, should be able to tweaking to support freeze frame):

1. [DaVinci Resolve 12 - 38b Clip Retiming (Contains retime clip interface, variable speed, freeze frame, accessing interface)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi7joxEoH2o)
2. [How to Make Quick Video Slideshow from Photo Using Openshot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6KbVrGNkRI)