# movie splitter or movie maker

Tags: split

I used once a programm called "movie splitter" or "movie splitzer". 
It was fantastic for split a movie in clips. Someone has it? Do you know how to get it?
I couldn't find any similar program. Is there one?
Thanks a lot

Comment: The software you ask for apparently is for Windows. For Ubuntu solutions see https://askubuntu.com/questions/56022/what-to-use-to-quickly-cut-audio-video http://askubuntu.com/questions/35605/splitting-an-mp4-file

Answer (score 2):

What I shortlisted is complement or alternative that not found on:

[What to use to quickly cut Audio/Video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56022/what-to-use-to-quickly-cut-audio-video)

To support Open Source culture, we should promote the best of Open Source of Video Editor such as [Shotcut](https://www.shotcutapp.com/download/), [Flowblade](http://jliljebl.github.io/flowblade/), [Pitivi](http://www.pitivi.org/)

However if the DAVINCI RESOLVE is really more users friendly and with equivalence feature, it is a good choice for those wanted to be hobbyist to amateurs, professional wannable etc

### List of Free/Open Source Linux's Video Editor:

1. [DAVINCI RESOLVE 12.5](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve)
2. [Cinelerra](http://cinelerra.org/)
3. [Shotcut](https://www.shotcutapp.com/download/)
4. [Lightworks Free](https://www.lwks.com/)
5. [ffDiaporama](http://ffdiaporama.tuxfamily.org/)
6. [WeVideo (1GB Video)](https://www.wevideo.com/)
7. [Flowblade](http://jliljebl.github.io/flowblade/)

### List of Commercial Linux's Video Editor:

1. [DAVINCI RESOLVE Studio 12.5, Free version (Subset) available](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve)
2. [Lightworks Pro](https://www.lwks.com/)

### List of Alternative in 3D or Visual Effect software that should able to work with Video Editing (Open Source / Industry grade's Free version):

1. [Editing in NUKE STUDIO: Part 1](https://vimeo.com/129084136)
2. [Using Blender as Video Editing Software on Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/using-blender-video-editing-software-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Try `PiTiVi` a free opensource tool available in internet. With `PiTiVi`, you can trim, snap, split, and cut a clip, and then, you can export it to various formats. You can also merge the video with a different audio clip, a feature that can be useful for a lot of people who like remixing videos and uploading them.

In some linux distros it is available as a default application.

Answer (score 0):

OpenShot video editor is one of the most used open source video editor.It is available in the software center. More info at http://www.openshot.org/