# Add title text over freezed frame in Kdenlive

Tags: video-editor, effects, kdenlive

Ubuntu 18.04

Kdenlive

I'm having difficulty overlaying text over a freezed frame: although I'm able to apply the motion freeze effect over my selected spliced clip, when I add title text on the track above, the freeze effect stops. This is quite cumbersome as I need to label specific components on selected frames.

I've referred to prior [posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886902/freeze-frame-video-editor) on the matter of freezed frames but saw nothing on difficulties with overlaid text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was [a known bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=378953). The Kdenlive codebase underwent a large refactoring for version 19.04, and it looks like it should be fixed in this and later versions.

Note that in this newer version, the context menu doesn't show all the effects anymore. So to find the freeze effect, you have to open the Effects pane (View > Effects) and go to the "Show all video effects" tab (the default view is the "Main effects" tab, and the freeze effect isn't visible here).